# What is the role of an Information Architect?

Tags: design, team, information, planning, user-experience

I've heard this term bandied about, especially in reference to web development, but I'm having trouble getting a clear understanding of what an Information Architect actually does.

Any ideas what their role or deliverables would be?

Comment: https://www.msu.edu/~wrac/pw/careers/infoarch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, an Information Architect decides how information will be organized and presented on a web site.  This would include navigation, aggregation, presentation (more *what* is presented than *how*) and access control (including security and filtering).  Think of them as responsible for "content design", as opposed to "site design".

Answer (score 1):

> **[I.A.I. definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Architect)**
>
> Information architecture is defined by the Information Architecture Institute as:
>
> 1. The structural design of shared information environments.
> 2. The art and science of organizing and labeling web sites, intranets, online communities, and software to support findability and usability.
> 3. An emerging community of practice focused on bringing principles of design and architecture to the digital landscape.

Comment: +1 for the link - they even have a journal: http://journalofia.org/

Comment: ...but what do they actually do?